# Wait and notify for 2 parallel running threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads t1 and t2 which will print 1 to 10. The t1 thread will print odd numbers while the t2 threads will print even numbers. I am confused that how would I know that this thread is t1 or t2 and the printing 1 to 10 should be done in sequence. I ended up doing this. Please suggest where I am I going wrong.

```
class Print implements Runnable{

Object odd = new Object();

public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++){

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")){
            synchronized(odd){
                    if ((i %2 !=0))
                    System.out.println(i + " Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                try {
                    odd.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t2")){  
        synchronized(odd){
                    if ((i %2 ==0)){
                    System.out.println(i + " Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    odd.notifyAll();
                }   
            }
        }

    }

}

}

public class EvenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Print obj1 = new Print();
            Print obj2 = new Print();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1, "t1");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2, "t2");
            t1.start();
            t2.start();

        }

    }
```

Output:

1 Thread - t1
2 Thread - t2
4 Thread - t2
6 Thread - t2
8 Thread - t2
10 Thread - t2

Comment: If u expect to behave in sequence, then why u need threads?

Comment: This is not about sequence but how I can control the execution of two parallel running threads to print 1 to 10. t1 prints 1 and waits for t2 to print 2 then t1 prints 3 and so on. Hope you got my point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no real synchronization between the threads. Each uses a different lock (i.e. it's own copy of "odd" member).

Also, in your implementation, there's nothing preventing the second thread from printing all even numbers and finishing quickly its loop. It never waits for thread #1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't new two `Print` that your `odd` is not shared.
I changed your code,it works as you expected:

```
    class Print implements Runnable{
       Object odd = new Object();

       public void run() {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
         if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")){
           synchronized(odd){
             if(i%2==0) 
               continue;
             System.out.println(i + " Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
             odd.notifyAll();
             odd.wait();
           }
         }else{
            synchronized(odd){
             if(i%2!=0) 
               continue;
             System.out.println(i + " Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
             odd.notifyAll();
             odd.wait();
           }
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

main code:

```
    Print obj1 = new Print()
    Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1, "t1")
    Thread t2 = new Thread(obj1, "t2")
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(10) //let t1 run first
    t2.start();
```

Comment: Thanks Fairjm. Now I understand that I was using two different copies of lock and hence the 2 threads ran independently producing unexpected behavior. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock on same object. Or make your lock object `static` (which is not good, btw) . Probably all synchronization logic should be done  on your `main` method and excluded from Print class.

Comment: Thanks Mytitle for the explanation. one more question. Why you said the static lock is not good and why should I synchronize in main? Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something in sequence as you do in your code, then it is not a candidate for threading. Threads only help if something can be done in parallel, so in your case i.E. if you do not care in which order the numbers are printed.